# different ui shows in CRT and LCD monitor

Tags: wpf, window, monitor, lcd

I've created a simple wpf project but it has diferent showing on crt monitors and lcd monitors:

CRT:

[image]

LCD:

[image]

as you can see the right part of CRT showings disappears even when maximized!

why is it so and how to solve it?

this is the xaml code of it:

```
<Window x:Class="MonitorTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 

    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized"  Top="0" Left="0" 
    Background="SkyBlue"
     SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >

<Grid  Background="SkyBlue"  Height="700" >
    <Grid Background="SkyBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-1,0,285" Name="grid3" Width="1286">
        <DataGrid BorderBrush="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="404" MinColumnWidth="60" Name="DataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="423" Margin="0,1,0,0">
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=X}" Header="X" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Y}" Header="Y" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Z}" Header="Z" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Q}" Header="Q" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=G}" Header="G" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Alpha}" Header="α" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Beta}" Header="β" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="404" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="429,1,0,0" MinColumnWidth="60" Name="DataGrid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367">
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=X}" Header="Xc" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Y}" Header="Yc" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Theta}" Header="θ" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Phi}" Header="φ" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Alpha}" Header="α" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Beta}" Header="β" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="404" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="802,1,0,0" MinColumnWidth="60" Name="MotorDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127">
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Alpha}" Header="α" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Beta}" Header="β" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="404" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="935,1,0,0" MinColumnWidth="60" Name="DataGrid3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342">
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Mdiff}" Header="M_Δα" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Ma_diff}" Header="H_Δα" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MB_diff}" Header="S_Δβ" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MBa_diff}" Header="H_Δβ" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Content="s4" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,549" Name="s4Label" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="242" />
        <Label Content="hSS" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,0,0,549" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="224" />
        <Label Content="Motor" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485,0,0,549" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" />
        <Grid Background="SlateGray" Height="257" Margin="21,0,0,-266" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="178">
            <Button Content="Config" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,12,0,0" Name="Config" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" />
            <Button Content="Init Sensors" Height="42" Margin="22,60,20,0" Name="InitButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" />
            <Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Start" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,108,0,0" Name="StartButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Click="Start_Click" />
            <Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Stop" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,156,0,0" Name="StopButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Click="Stop_Click" />
            <Button Content="Stop" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="False" Margin="22,203,0,0" Name="StopSButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Click="Stop_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <TextBox Background="WhiteSmoke" Height="249" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,424,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Different [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) of monitors?

Comment: @KonradKokosa, yes both 96 pixel per inch

Comment: could you post the xaml for the same?

Comment: @pushpraj, the code has been added.

Comment: do you have any requirement of fixed size or the controls? ie. pixels or cm or inches. or the numbers in xaml is just to make it look better?

Comment: just to make it look better.

Answer (score 2):

Containers plays an important role in defining the UI. So leverage them to make the UI flexible.

When you code a UI using WPF, avoid using Width, Height etc. unless necessary. try to use containers like Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel etc.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152):

> The WPF includes a comprehensive suite of derived panel implementations that enable many complex layouts. These derived classes expose properties and methods that enable most standard user interface (UI) scenarios. Developers who are unable to find a child arrangement behavior that meets their needs can create new layouts by overriding the ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride methods. For more information on custom layout behaviors, see Custom Panel Elements.

If you still have to define height, width etc. numbers then define with the measurement unit eg 0.05in or 5pt, this way WPF will attempt to keep the size constant to various resolutions by varying number of pixels. this is known as [DIP(Device-independent pixels)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173)

I have attempted to make the UI remains re-sizable based on the available screen space, so it will attempt to fit to the screen with best possible appearance

xaml

```
<Grid Background="SkyBlue">
    <Grid Margin="0.05in">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="grid3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="gridStyle"
                       TargetType="DataGrid">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns"
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="0.02in" />
                    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns"
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns"
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows"
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection"
                            Value="LeftToRight" />
                    <Setter Property="MinColumnWidth"
                            Value="60" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                            Value="1" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                            Value="SemiBold" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="0.05in,0" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource gridStyle}"
                      x:Name="DataGrid1">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding X}"
                                        Header="X" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Y}"
                                        Header="Y" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Z}"
                                        Header="Z" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Q}"
                                        Header="Q" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding G}"
                                        Header="G" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Alpha}"
                                        Header="α" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Beta}"
                                        Header="β" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource gridStyle}"
                      x:Name="DataGrid2"
                      Grid.Column="1">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding X}"
                                        Header="Xc" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Y}"
                                        Header="Yc" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Theta}"
                                        Header="θ" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Phi}"
                                        Header="φ" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Alpha}"
                                        Header="α" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Beta}"
                                        Header="β" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource gridStyle}"
                      x:Name="MotorDataGrid"
                      Grid.Column="2">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Alpha}"
                                        Header="α" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Beta}"
                                        Header="β" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource gridStyle}"
                      x:Name="DataGrid3"
                      Grid.Column="3">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mdiff}"
                                        Header="M_Δα" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Ma_diff}"
                                        Header="H_Δα" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MB_diff}"
                                        Header="S_Δβ" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MBa_diff}"
                                        Header="H_Δβ" />

                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
            <TextBlock Text="s4"
                       x:Name="s4Label" />
            <TextBlock Text="hSS"
                       x:Name="label2"
                       Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="Motor"
                       x:Name="label3"
                       Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="0,.05in,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="2in" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="SlateGray"
                    CornerRadius="4"
                    x:Name="grid1">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Setter Property="Width"
                                    Value="1.5in" />
                            <Setter Property="Height"
                                    Value=".45in" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin"
                                    Value=".2in, 0.05in" />
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Button Content="Config"
                            Margin=".2in, .1in,.2in,.05in"
                            x:Name="Config" />
                    <Button Content="Init Sensors"
                            x:Name="InitButton" />
                    <Button IsEnabled="False"
                            Content="Start"
                            x:Name="StartButton"
                            Click="Start_Click" />
                    <Button IsEnabled="False"
                            Content="Stop"
                            x:Name="StopButton"
                            Click="Stop_Click" />
                    <Button Content="Stop"
                            IsEnabled="False"
                            Margin=".2in, .05in,.2in,.1in"
                            x:Name="StopSButton"
                            Click="Stop_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <TextBox Background="WhiteSmoke"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     x:Name="textBox1"
                     Margin=".1in,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

result

wide screen (Laptop, LCD, Widescreen TV, HDMI displays etc.)

[image: wide screen]

4:3 (CRT Monitor, old 4:3 LCDs etc.)

[image: 4:3]

give it a try and share your feedback

Comment: ,yet the same problem. I executed your code but has the same problem.How can I send the feedback(pictures,code,...) here?(make them as a part of question? or send as email to you?)

Comment: this is the image of the code you said: http://i.imgur.com/aOq4NYr.png , http://i.imgur.com/QQKLNxx.png , http://i.imgur.com/u6FJmQi.png

Comment: the layout which I give is based on my assumptions on your code, you may adjust as per your needs. currently bottom panel has a fixed height and the width is adjusted dynamically. as per your code i assumed a minimum width of 1286 and height of 700. however the UI can adapt to slightly lower resolutions too. perhaps you can post a picture of how you want it to be along with some rules for the panels eg how they shrink or expand when screen size changes. may I give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your LDC monitor is widescreen and your CRT monitor is not.
Widescreen monitors preview wider desktops. 
Your app is the same, but you don't see part of it because it overflows.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

Comment: You can't. Your app is too big. You must decrease element size or remove something.